# Using thymeleaf variable in onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, spring, onclick, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my current spring-boot project, I have one view with this html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="upload()" th:utext="#{modal.save}"></button>
```

in the `onclick` attribute, the call for the function `upload()` should have one parameter, which value is stored in the thymeleaf variable `${gallery}`.

Anyone can tell mehow to use the expression in the above command?

I already try this:

- `th:onclick="upload(${gallery)"`
- `th:attr="onclick=upload(${gallery)"`

None of this worked.

Comment: Just as a heads-up: Visitors to this question may want to take a look at the following Thymeleaf ticket from 2018: [Avoid variable expressions returning strings in event handlers](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/705). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726362/how-to-pass-arguments-to-javascript-function-call-when-using-onclick-in-thymelea).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I solve this issue with this approach:

```
th:onclick="|upload('${command['class'].simpleName}', '${gallery}')|"
```

Comment: At now (2020) it seems does not work anymore: 
Error: Only variable expressions returning numbers or booleans are allowed in this context, any other datatypes are not trusted

Comment: At now the answer here its working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52960571/373498

Answer (score 59):

thymeleaf 3.0.10 th:onclick
thymeleaf variable not working

This should work:

```
th:attr="onclick=|upload('${gallery}')|"
```

Comment: Really? You can find th:onclick in the docs for thymleaf 3.0. I'm pretty shure the attribute isn't kicked out for version 3.0.10

Comment: This is the correct answer because since version 3.0.10, thymeleaf doesn't support variables of type other than Boolean and Integer inside `th:onclick="..."`. So if you want to pass a non-boolean and non-integer argument to the `onclick()` method, `th:onclick="..."` won't work. You have to use `th:attr="onclick=..."` as shown in this answer.

Answer (score 14):

This should work:

```
<button th:onclick="'javascript:upload(' + ${gallery} + ')'"></button>
```

Comment: This works perfectly but you've left out the closing brace '}'. Should be `<button th:onclick="'javascript:upload(' + ${gallery} + ')'"></button>`. Also you might need to enclose _gallery_ in quotes if it is a String parameter, so `<button th:onclick="'javascript:upload('\' + ${gallery} + '\')'"></button>`.

Comment: @phn Added the missing brace. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @cnpfm this answer is more suitable for my problem in Thymeleaf 2

Answer (score 11):

In 3.0.10 version of Thymeleaf

use [[ ]]  it's more easier  , thymeleaf goes to inject the value in template

if the value is string no quote need

```
<button th:data-id="${quartzInfo.id}" 
    th:onclick="del(this,[[${quartzInfo.id}]]" type="button">
</button>
```

Comment: This worked for me!!

Comment: This is missing the closing parentheses for the 'del' method

Answer (score 6):

The older replies does not work in the new version of 3.0.10. Now you need:

```
<button th:data-id="${quartzInfo.id}" 
    onclick="del(this,this.getAttribute('data-id'))" type="button">
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

In fact this one is working too :

```
th:attr="onclick=${'upload('+gallery+')'}"
```

Comment: `th:attr="onclick=${'upload('''+gallery+''')'}"` make it like so to wrap single quotes  around the object within bracket

Answer (score 2):

yes it's to late, but i hope this will help people who need it

try this

```
th:onclick="'upload('+${gallery}+')'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `attr`, where there is a string the `HTML` will crash and you have to do the following, in case of string values.

```
th:attr="onclick=${'toggleContractLine('+ ''' + contract.id + ''' + ')'}"
```

Comment: It might be one more of those `'` this worked for me  `<span th:attr="onclick=${'doThis('+ '''' + user.getTestJquery() + '''' + ')'}">aaaa</span>`