# How to pass arguments to javascript function call when using onClick in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have been calling my javascript function from Thymeleaf as below:

```
th:onclick="'viewDocument(\'' + ${document.docTypeLongDesc} +'\');'"
```

But I just updated my spring boot version to 2.1.4 RELEASE with which Thymeleaf also got updated. And the previous version in no longer supported.

On further research I found out that I should be able to use

```
th:onclick="' viewDocument (this.getAttribute ('document.docTypeLongDesc'));'"
```

However, it doesn't give any error but neither does it work. I have removed the argument and was able to call the function just fine. So I am guessing I am not passing the argument right way. Any guidance will be helpful. TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this: [Restricted mode: Avoid variable expressions returning strings in processors for event handlers (th:on*)](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/705).

In order to correctly pass Thymeleaf variables to the onclick event, put the variable in a `data` attribute, and read it using `getAttribute()`.

```
th:data-longDescription="${document.docTypeLongDesc}" onclick="viewDocument(this.getAttribute('data-longDescription'));"
```

Comment: I referred the same link and use it the same way but still getting the runtime error: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "templates/th_documentsDetails.html") .   Also Intellij highlight this.getAttribute as red and on highlighting says can't recognize. I am thinking it's most likely a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: @ILRNew Did you notice that I'm no longer using `th:onclick`, now it's just a regular `onclick` as it no longer needs to be a thymeleaf expression.

Comment: You are actually right. I didn't notice that. Once I did that it work like a charm. thank you very much. Can I ask you on how to learn more about new Thymeleaf?

Answer (score -2):

You should use it as follows:

```
th:onclick="${'viewDocument(' + document.docTypeLongDesc + ');'}"
```