# How to change th:attr to th:onclick in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

When I use the attribute `th:attr` everything is working.

But when I want to use `th:onclick` without `th:attr`, I have error.
What do I need to do to make it work well without `th:attr`?

```
<button th:each="user : ${users}"
        th:if="(${user.id} == ${user.id})"
        th:attr="onclick='changeUser(\''+ ${user.id} + '\', \''+ ${user.name} + '\');'">click on me</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass arguments to javascript function call when using onClick in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726362/how-to-pass-arguments-to-javascript-function-call-when-using-onclick-in-thymelea)

Comment: Note that after using the approach in the linked answer, you will no longer need to use `th:onclick`. You can just use `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is in Thymeleaf version. [image]

Comment: You can choose to do this, but be aware that the Thymeleaf version "problem" was deliberately added to Thymeleaf as a safety feature. The creators of Thymeleaf recommend that you "_use (adequately HTML-escaped) data- attributes for text literal variables,_" - see their notes [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/705) and also the answer I linked to in my comments in the question.