# Having multiple forms on my page triggers an unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have multiple forms on my page each one with a different id (dynamically populated from a database) and I tried using JavaScript to replace some classes and dynamically add the file name after upload.

I don't know why even if the ids are totally unique I get a strange behavior: whatever is the form in which I submit a file JavaScript will apply changes always on the first of them.

I have my JavaScript code attached in the same div of each form right after the `</form>` closing tag.

```js
function spinnerLoad(){

  document.getElementById('file-name[[${id}]]').textContent = this.files[0].name;
      
  document.getElementById('spinner[[${id}]]').classList.replace('fas', 'spinner-border');
  document.getElementById('spinner[[${id}]]').classList.replace('fa-file-upload', 'spinner-border-sm');
  document.getElementById('uploadForm[[${id}]]').submit()

}
```

I'm using Bootstrap for my styling rules.

```html
/*${id} variable is server-side and it's there to make unique each form, I'm using Thymeleaf template engine*/
<form th:id="'uploadForm'+${id}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/upload/{id} (id=${id})}">
    <label for="file-upload" class="btn btn-outline-success">
        <span th:id="'spinner'+${id}" class="fas fa-file-upload"></span> <b>Upload file:</b> <i th:id="'file-name'+${id}">No file selected</i>
    </label>
    <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="multipartFile"  accept="application/pdf" style="display: none" th:onchange="spinnerLoad()"/>
</form>
```

I had a look on Google but I didn't manage to find a specific answer to my problem.

If you want to test this snippet on your own you can put instead of ${id} whatever number you like, it just has to be unique. And of course you will have to test it with at least 2 different forms.

Comment: If you have two or more functions in your page, as you have described, and they are all called `spinnerLoad()`, then the last function in the page will always be invoked. Its definition replaces all previous definitions of that specifically named function - even if they are in separate script tags.

Comment: You can give your functions different names, or you can create only one function and pass in the relevant ID from the click event. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726362/how-to-pass-arguments-to-javascript-function-call-when-using-onclick-in-thymelea) for an example of passing Thymeleaf arguments to that function. You can also use an event handler, such as [this](https://api.jquery.com/on/), instead of using `th:onchange="spinnerLoad()` in each form.

Comment: Ok I see what your are saying, what if I just put my JavaScript into th:onchange="/*JavaScript code here*/" without using a function name?

Comment: Btw I had a look at the link you provided me about passing Thymeleaf arguments. I tried that but I always get the same behaviour: whatever is the form in which I submit a file JavaScript will apply changes always on the first of them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us how you handle your forms, "*each one with a different id*", so I have used the following assumption.

In my Java code, I use the following (assuming plain Thymeleaf):

```java
model.put("id_a", "123");
model.put("id_b", "456");
```

Or, if this is a Spring-based application, maybe this:

```java
model.addAttribute("id_a", "123");
model.addAttribute("id_b", "456");
```

But in both cases, this is where we define our unique IDs - one for each HTML form. And the `model` is how we pass those variables to our Thymeleaf template, in the usual way.

Then, in the Thymeleaf template we have this:

```html
<body>

    <form th:id="'uploadForm'+${id_a}" 
          method="post" 
          enctype="multipart/form-data" 
          th:action="@{/upload/{id_a} (id=${id_a})}">
        <label for="file-upload" class="btn btn-outline-success">
            <span th:id="'spinner'+${id_a}" 
                  class="fas fa-file-upload">
            </span> 
            <b>Upload file:</b> 
            <i th:id="'file-name'+${id_a}">No file selected</i>
        </label>
        <input id="file-upload" 
               th:data-unique-id="${id_a}"
               type="file" 
               name="multipartFile"  
               accept="application/pdf"  
               onchange="spinnerLoad(this.getAttribute('data-unique-id'))"/>
    </form>

    <form th:id="'uploadForm'+${id_b}" 
          method="post" 
          enctype="multipart/form-data" 
          th:action="@{/upload/{id_b} (id=${id_b})}">
        <label for="file-upload" class="btn btn-outline-success">
            <span th:id="'spinner'+${id_b}" 
                  class="fas fa-file-upload">
            </span> 
            <b>Upload file:</b> 
            <i th:id="'file-name'+${id_b}">No file selected</i>
        </label>
        <input id="file-upload" 
               th:data-unique-id="${id_b}"
               type="file" 
               name="multipartFile"  
               accept="application/pdf"  
               onchange="spinnerLoad(this.getAttribute('data-unique-id'))"/>
    </form>

    <script>
        function spinnerLoad(id) {
            console.log(id);
            document.getElementById('file-name' + id).textContent = this.files[0].name;
            document.getElementById('spinner' + id).classList.replace('fas', 'spinner-border');
            document.getElementById('spinner' + id).classList.replace('fa-file-upload', 'spinner-border-sm');
            document.getElementById('uploadForm' + id).submit()
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Each form uses its own unique ID - `${id_a}` or `${id_b}`, and there is only one `spinnerLoad()` function. The function is called using:

```
onchange="spinnerLoad(this.getAttribute('data-unique-id'))"
```

And the value of `this.getAttribute('data-unique-id')` is the value provided by `th:data-unique-id="${id_a}"` and `th:data-unique-id="${id_b}"`.

So, the passed parameter will be `123` or `456`. And then the `spinnerLoad` function will operate on the correct elements.

The above technique is what is described in the answer I linked to.

You asked:

> *what if I just put my JavaScript into th:onchange="/*JavaScript code here*/" without using a function name?*

No, you cannot do that, for security reasons, to avoid the execution of arbitrary code containing user-provided (and therefore potentially unsafe) data. That is actually the whole point of the technique in the answer - to provide a safe workaround for that limitation.

---

Additional notes:

If you don't want to have multiple separate blocks of `<form>` HTML, you can provide your unique IDs in a Java `List` and iterate over the list in Thymeleaf - similar to how table rows are built in this [documentation example](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#using-theach).

As also noted in the comments you can replace the `onchange="spinnerLoad(this.getAttribute('data-unique-id'))"` attributes with an event handler - but that is basically the same underlying approach as the one shown above, in terms of how the unique IDs are handled.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, you were very helpful. I had to work on it to properly fit in my project, but it was great! Thanks!!!