# thymeleaf th:onclick passing a list attribute to javascript function

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

From Springboot I create an attribute having a list as value:

```
attributes.addFlashAttribute("mylist", mylist);
```

On client-side a need to pass this list to a javascript function. I used:

```
<th scope="col">
       <i class="fas fa-plus" type="button" 
      th:onclick="|myfunction('staticValue', [[${mylist}]]);|">
      </i>
</th>
```

The result is that the th tag disappear from the table. The javascript works when I do not use the thymeleaf attribute. I'm using thymeleaf 3.0.15.

As suggested I'm also using with no success:

```
<i class="fas fa-plus" type="button" 
   th:data-materialTypeSetDes="${mylist}"
   onclick="function('staticValue', this.getAttribute('data-materialTypeSetDes'));"></i>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass arguments to javascript function call when using onClick in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726362/how-to-pass-arguments-to-javascript-function-call-when-using-onclick-in-thymelea)

Comment: No, I have updated the question, maybe I introduced another typo

Comment: Thank you for trying. In that case, we probably need a [mre]. The updated code you show in your question works for me (except I'm not using Font Awesome, which I do not think is relevant to your issue). At the very least, can you show what gets rendered? The data in the Java `List` should be shown - something like `data-materialTypeSetDes="[foo, bar]"`. A MRE may make this clearer.