# Thymeleaf preprocessed expression cannot have brankets appended

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

No matter whether I append () or () at the end of the preprocessed expression, Thymeleaf doesn't substitute the preprocessed expression with its value. Strange enough, But it looks Ok the preprocessed expression append "aa"

Here is the html:

```html
<* href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" th:onclick="submit__${container.name}\__()" style="width:80px">Submit</*>
<* href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" th:onclick="submit__${container.name}__aa" style="width:80px">Clear</*>
```

Here is the html source after Thymeleaf transformed.

```html
<* href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="submit__${container.name}__()" style="width:80px">Submit<*/>
<* href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="submitformaa" style="width:80px">Clear</*>
```

Please help me out of this as it drives me to the wall. Thanks

Comment: Does this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650536/using-thymeleaf-variable-in-onclick-attribute solves your problem?

Comment: They are different issues. Have tried it anyway and it didn't work at all.